# convert pdf into base64 and append in a json array

Tags: python, json

I've a two pdf file in my directory.

I want to store the data based on number of pdf available in the repo. Since there are two pdfs, it is

```
[{ "name" : "filename1",
   "data" : encoded_data1,
   "ContentType": "application/octet-stream"},
 { "name" : "filename2",
   "data" : encoded_data2,
   "ContentType": "application/octet-stream"}
]
```

If there's only one pdf, then json array be like

```
[{ "name" : "filename1",
   "data" : encoded_data1,
   "ContentType": "application/octet-stream"}
]
```

I'm reading the pdf and converting into base64 format.

```
files = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'pdf']

for f in files:
       data = open(f, 'rb').read()
       encoded_data = base64.b64encode(data).decode('UTF-8')
```

I'm trying to store the encoded data of pdf in a variable, but it gets rewritten. Is there any other way, I could achieve this dynamically. Because creating two variables for 2 files and appending the data is so static and also fails if there's only one file.

Comment: *"...,but it gets rewritten."* - what gets rewritten? `encoded_data`? Of course it gets rewritten as you are rewriting it every iteration of the for loop. Are you trying to achieve something like `encoded_data = []` (place before for loop)  and `encoded_data.append(...)` inside for loop instead of `encoded_data = ...` ?

Comment: But how do I achieve like a json array with all the details? My problem is that I have to create a json array with data of the pdfs. I'm having a problem in creating json key-value pairs and appending in an array, file-by-file.

Comment: Append a [dictionary](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) to some [list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp), inside a for loop?

Comment: @Vepir Thanks, I got my solution.